# Ruby - How to send a text string from a TCP Server to a client on a different computer with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tcp

I've been trying to learn this for days and nothing is working. When I write code like this
for the client.

```
require 'socket'
tcp_client=TCPSocket.new('localhost',2000)
while grab_string=tcp_client.gets
puts(grab_string)
end
tcp_client.close
```

and code like this for the server.

```
# Set up a server program.
require 'socket'
tcp_server=TCPServer.new(2000)
loop{
waiting_client=tcp_server.accept
path='C:\Users\Nil_Face\Music\Bad Religion - Anxiety.mp3'
test=File.new(path,'rb')
waiting_client.puts(File.basename(path))
test.close
waiting_client.close
}
```

It works just fine but when I use that server on my desktop and try to get that text string to appear on the client located on a different computer. It doesn't work. Why won't the client connect to the server when their both on different computers? And how can I get them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is connecting to 'localhost', which is the same computer where the client runs.

```
tcp_client=TCPSocket.new('localhost',2000)
```

The client should be connecting to the hostname/ip of the machine on which the server is running.  Change 'localhost' with the IPv4 address / inet addr of the server machine, in this case '192.168.1.10'.

On windows:

```
ipconfig
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local.domain
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
```

On Linux:

```
# /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

If you're getting connection timed out. You can try connecting with telnet from the command prompt:

```
telnet 192.168.1.10 2000
```

From the server computer, you can also verify that the server is running and is accepting connections with netstat:

```
netstat -an
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If those are all correct, you probably have a firewall that is blocking the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems so obvious to me now. But either way It still didn't really work because I just got an error saying "Error A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly repspond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host had failed to respond"